# Print field only if value is not empty

Tags: php

I have a foreach statement that prints the label and values of some fields:

```
<?php 
   foreach ($this->item->dpfields as $field) {
      echo '<li><b>'.$field->label.'</b>: '.$field->value.'</li>';
   }
?>
```

I would like to print only the fields (labels and values) that are not empty.

How should I edit this code?

Comment: [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
    foreach ($this->item->dpfields as $field) {
        if (!empty($field->label) && !empty($field->value)) {
             echo '<li><b>'.$field->label.'</b>: '.$field->value.'</li>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Edit according to comment how to avoid empty list and set class according to number of elements:

```
<?php 
    $itemCnt = count($this->item->dpfields);
    if ($itemCnt > 0) { 
        /* 
         * If there are more than one items in the list set col-md-6 and col-lg-6, 
         * otherwise set col-md-12 and col-lg-12 
         * (col-xs-12 and col-sm-12 are the same for both)
         */
        $liClass = ($itemCnt>1) ? 'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6' : 'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12';
        echo '<ul class="projectdetails">'; 
        foreach ($this->item->dpfields as $field) { 
            if (!empty($field->value)) { 
                echo '<li class="' . $liClass . '"><b>'.$field->label.'</b>: '.$field->value.'</li>'; 
            } 
        } 
        echo '</ul>'; 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Adreas, it worked. Now how should I write another "if" <ul class="projectdetails">
   <?php 
    foreach ($this->item->dpfields as $field) {
     if (!empty($field->value)) {
      echo '<li><b>'.$field->label.'</b>: '.$field->value.'</li>';
     }
    }
   ?>
  </ul>

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment!. I would ask how to incapsulate the <ul>...PHP ode before ...</ul> to hide it if all fields are empty.

Comment: To hide the `<ul>` if all fields are empty you can encapsulate your whole list in `if (count($this->item->dpfields) > 0) {...}`

Comment: I've tryed this: <?php if (count($this->item->dpfields) > 0) {
  <ul class="projectdetails">
    foreach ($this->item->dpfields as $field) {
     if (!empty($field->value)) {
      echo '<li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><b>'.$field->label.'</b>: '.$field->value.'</li>';
     }
    }
  </ul>
  }
  ?> but seems not working...

Comment: You have neither closed the php-Tag before the `<ul>` nore echoed it ;) I've added it to the post above for better readability

Comment: Last question Andreas... How could I (you...) edit the previous code for this condition: if I have only 1 <li> I would change the <li> class to <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">. How to? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: For this you can also use the ´count()´. I would set a variable named `$liClass` and then check if theres only one ore more than one elements - I've updated the example once more :)

Comment: Does it count also empty fields? I've filled only 1 field but the class applyed is still "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"

Comment: It counts all fields contained in `$this->item->dpfields`. Have you also edited the `class="' . $liClass . '"` part? It's easy to oversee that. If there are empty fields in dpfields, you can try to filter those out using e.g. `array_walk()` (http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-walk.php).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126646/discussion-between-francesco-and-andreas).

Comment: I've done this test: I've printed the variable $itemCnt (echo '<li class="' . $liClass . '"><b>'.$field->label.'</b>: '.$field->value.'</li> <b>' . $itemCnt .'</b>'; ) and it says "5" ! But I have filled only one field.

Comment: The number "5" seems to be the number of the the fields. So it counts the number of fields, meanwhile I need that it counts only the number of fields not empty. Any idea?

Comment: solved this way: $itemCnt = 0;
   
   foreach ($this->item->dpfields as $field) { 
    if (!empty($field->value)) { 
     $itemCnt = $itemCnt+1; 
    } 
   }

Comment: Sorry, had to left before. Yes this works. Other possibilty could have been the usage of `array_walk` (linked above). This walks over an array and keeps only elements that meet a certain condition (in your case that `$field->value` is not empty) in the array. The exact usage can be found in documentation. I'm sure you can handle this ;) The `array_walk()` has to be called before the `$itemCnt = count(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php 
  foreach ($this->item->dpfields as $field) {
    if($field->label!="" && $field->value!="") 
    {
       echo '<li><b>'.$field->label.'</b>: '.$field->value.'</li>';
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This work if `$field` is defined:

```
<?php 
    if (count($this->item->dpfields) > 0) {
        foreach ($this->item->dpfields as $field) {
            if (!empty($field->label) && !empty($field->value) {
                echo '<li><b>'.$field->label.'</b>: '.$field->value.'</li>'; 
            } 
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>No results</p>';
    }

?>
```

You can also use: `if (!empty($this->item->dpfields))`. It's the same.

`empty()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    foreach ($this->item->dpfields as $field) {
      if(!empty($field->label) && !empty($field->value){
        echo '<li><b>'.$field->label.'</b>: '.$field->value.'</li>';
      }
    }
?>
```

Try this :)